# Which service automatically adjusts screen brightness in Ubuntu 20?

Tags: lenovo

I want to uninstall the service responsible for automatically adjusting the screen brightness in Ubuntu. I uninstalled it in my previous installation of Ubuntu and forgot it's name now. It just doesn't work properly with Ubuntu 20 and Lenovo yoga 7 pro slim amd cpu and graphics. Could someone please help with the name of the service?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20 so what is the actual version of Ubuntu you are running?

Comment: I man Ubuntu 20.04 specificall. BTW the package is iio-sensor-proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out, it's iio-sensor-proxy package. This package malfunctions with Ubuntu 20.04 and Lenovo yoga 7 slim pro with amd graphics. Removing this package solves some problems.